# Resonator guitar pickup

Tags: amplifier, guitar, pickup

I bought an used resonator guitar from eBay, and I found out it has some kind of pickup.

A pickup is a nice-to-have feature, no must-feature.

I have not seen a pickup like this before. It has no battery. After I connected it with my amplifier, no sound came out of it. I think this is just logical, since a pickup usually requires a battery.

So my question is, what is this and how can I use a pickup like this? Or maybe it is just a fake, to sell it better?

Note that there is a white strap under that black thing, so it is meant to be removeable.

[image: Pickup]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a  [piezo-electric transducer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pickup_%28music_technology%29#Piezoelectric_pickups), which wouldn't need a battery. Most types of pickup don't use batteries, as far as I can remember.

I can't say why you're not getting any output, though.

Comment: Yep - it shouldn't need any power. Output should be around the same as a normal passive pickup, so check the wires and connections inside that socket.

Comment: Acoustic pickups normally do because they use condenser mics, but yeah, this is a piezo-electric transducer or a contact mic, neither of which should need power.